# PHP regular expression not working with string from database

Tags: php, regex

`preg_replace` does not return desired result when I use it on string fetched from database.

```
$result = DB::connection("connection")->select("my query");
foreach($result as $row){

    //prints run-d.m.c.
    print($row->artist . "\n");

    //should print run.d.m.c
    //prints run-d.m.c
    print(preg_replace("/-/", ".", $row->artist) . "\n");
}
```

This occurs only when i try to replace `-` (dash). I can replace any other character.
However if I try this regex on simple string it works as expected:

```
$str = "run-d.m.c";

//prints run.d.m.c
print(preg_replace("/-/", ".", $str) . "\n");
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: If you use `'/\p{Pd}/'` pattern, do you match the hyphen/dash?

Comment: no, still prints same string

Comment: Then,  there might be just no `-` in the string. Not sure if it might help, try also adding `/u` modifier, `/\p{Pd}/u`.

Comment: Can you show the exact output?

Comment: It's likely that what looks like a dash is in reality a minus sign or another kind of dash (which may be different characters).

Comment: Combination of `/\p{Pd}/` and `u` modifier worked! Thank you @WiktorStribiżew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out you have Unicode dashes in your strings. To match all Unicode dashes, use

```
/[\p{Pd}\xAD]/u
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FLaRaB/2)

The `\p{Pd}` matches any hyphen in the [*Unicode Character Category 'Punctuation, Dash'*](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Pd/list.htm) but a soft hyphen, `\xAD`, hence it should be combined with `\p{Pd}` in a character class.

The `/u` modifier makes the pattern Unicode aware and makes the regex engine treat the input string as Unicode code point sequence, not a byte sequence.